# Node js serving old versions of modified angular files (instead on new ones)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm programming a project using the MEAN stack. All fine, except with the static files.

I have some rules in the Node router file to serve the static files. And it's working, but then I have done a change on an Angular file, but the Node server is returning me the old version of this file (before the changes).

Why is this happening?

Mainly, my server routing code is this one:

```
var app = express();

app.use("/node_modules/angular", express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular'));
app.use("/scripts", express.static(__dirname + '/public/scripts'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});
```

Comment: your question title is opposite to the issue you described in the question body. Please correct one or another

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that express will cache your static files because they really shouldn't change like Yevgen said. It's why you'll often see stuff like `mainSOMENUMBER.css` in production. So everytime you update a resource file like `main.css` or in this case `app.js` you add a version number to it and then change the source.

Long story short here is your fix.

```
app.use("/node_modules/angular", 
express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular'){maxage: 0});
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using such setup only for development process. Ideally static file should never change, the new version of the file should be reflected in new file name. By default express static middleware servs the new version of the file without server restart. I could suggest in your case to setup [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) or [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to watch on file changes in your static folder and trigger server restart.

Comment: I don't understand. Why I need nodemon (an automation tool) for restart the node server? And why is nodemon going to be succesful if my "manual" restarts aren't?

Comment: oh, I assumed that manual restart solves your problem, than probably it is a cache related issue with the browser

Comment: No, that's the matter. Even if I restart the computer the problem persists.